# import a single function

Tags: python, function, import

I'm just learning python so sorry for what is probably a simple question.

Following Zed Shaw's 'learn python the hard way' I made a little text game (ex36). It defines the functions start() and litroom(), then runs start(), which in turn runs litroom() depending on user input.

How would I import only the litroom() function to another file? If I try

```
from ex36 import litroom
```

it seems to import the lot and run start().

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Import syntax is correct. Paste your code.

Comment: embed your code in `ex36`in the magic `if __name__=='__main_':` so it does not get executed at import

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you import from ex36, it will read the whole file and execute any code not inside function.

If you have

```
def start():
   print ("hello")
def litroom():
   start()
start()
```

in your `ex36` file, your statement `import ex36` or `from ex36 import litroom` will execute start. You should fix the code like that:

```
def start():
   print ("hello")
def litroom():
   start()

if __name__=='__main__':
   # magix trick : name value is the name of the file 
   # unless run as the "main" script where it's __main__
   start()
```

You can see [What does if __name__ == "__main__": do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do)